# How to Hide Portlet in WebSphere Portal Server v8.5?

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

I have a portlet in the page and I am not allowed to remove it. I need to hide the portlet completely for any user in the WebSphere Portal Server 8.5.... Please let me know the steps

Answer (score 2):

remove access for all authenticated portal users and all anonymous users from the portlet itself

your other option is create a visibility rule for the portlet and set it to always be false